# GLMM: How to impose a specific parameter (intercept or slope) for the model?

Tags: linear-model, random-effects-model, glmm, offset

Good afternoon,

I would like to know if it’s possible and how to specify parameters in a GLMM.
Let’s take the example of a GLMM with random intercepts. In the following equation, the vector of fixed effects  (constant slopes) is represented by β, while the set of random intercepts is captured by α.
Yi = αj[i] + βxi
In that situation, I would like to impose the value 1 to β. I would like to force the GLMM to find the best α parameter for each group without considering a β parameter.

Then I would like to do the same with a GLMM with random slopes, but by imposing the value 0 to β0:
Yi = β0 + βj[i]xi

I would like to construct both of these models with the same data and then compare them to know if the relationship between y and x is better explained by a ratio (y = ax) or a difference (y = x+b). And at the meanwhile, considering those parameters can be different for each group.

Comment: For your first model simply fit the model $Y_{i} - X_{i}=\alpha_{j,i}$ and  $Y_{i} =\beta_{j,i}X_{i}$ for the second

Comment: Use an *offset* in the model statement. For examples and more information, look through the tag [tag:offset]